# Neo4J API Rest: Create UNIQUE relationship or return FAIL without indexing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was wondering whether it is possible to create a relationship or return fail if it exists through a Cypher query via REST. Besides, I do not want to create any kind of index.

This is my use case: User can like a comment only once. So I want to create the relationship (User)-[:LIKES]->(Comment) or return fail if it exists, using a Cypher query via REST.

My approach is to use CREATE UNIQUE and RETURN some kind of code that I will interpret in my back-end to know if I have to send 409 Conflict to the back-end's client. But this approach seems messy...

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to put a property in your `LIKES` relationship you could do something like this.

```
WITH timestamp() AS now
MERGE (user)-[like:LIKES]->(comment)
ON CREATE SET like.created_at = timestamp()
RETURN like.created_at >= now
```

If the query returns `true` you know the like was created otherwise it existed previously and you can handle it accordingly.